# maven parallel test and compilation

Tags: maven

Is it possible, in a maven multi module build, to already run tests on already compiled modules, while other modules further down the dependency graph are still compiling?

It also would be handy if depending modules could already compile as soon as the previous module is compiled (and do test-compile in parallel).

[edit] I tried `-T` parameter. It somehow does not parallelize as I described.

Comment: Using the -T option is not enough?

Comment: Can you please explain what this: `It somehow does not parallelize as I described.` means?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Thread Count param

```
mvn -T 1.5C clean install
```

The build executes multiple modules which can be executed respecting the dependency graph of your project.

Comment: I tried -T parameter. It somehow does not parallelize as I described.